# Lambda sorting in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, lambda

I was working on python2 for my project.Now I want to migrate from python2 to python3. I am getting syntax error while writing the for loop code snippet given below.I'm bit confused where I went wrong.

**Code :**

```
for k, val in sorted(datasource_columns.iteritems(), key=lambda(
                            k, v): sort_order.index(k)):
                        # columns.add_column(key, sorted(val))
                        columns.add_column(k, val)
```

where , **sort_order = ['Name', 'Data Type', 'Type', 'Role']**

Comment: Please include the actual error in your post.

Comment: `sort_order.index(k)` sounds like a very inefficient sort key...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already said, `iteritems()` will be a problem, but you mention a syntax error, which comes from the `lambda` declaration with parenthesis:

Change:

```
key=lambda(k, v): sort_order.index(k)
```

To:

```
key=lambda k, v: sort_order.index(k)
```

But you may as well write this more efficient code:

```
for key in sort_order:
    val = datasource_columns.get(key)
    if val is not None: # to avoid getting None values in your columns
        columns.add_column(key, val)
```

In the future, please post the actual stacktrace whenever you get an exception, this makes it a lot easier to understand any issue.

Comment: Your more efficient code has a slight problem: there may be keys in `sort_order` that aren't present in `datasource_columns`. Your code will create a `(key, None)` item for such keys. That may not be desirable.

Comment: Indeed, but that can be easily fixed with an `if val is not None:` statement, if required.

Comment: Certainly! So you should add that info to your answer. And it's probably worthwhile mentioning why the original key function is so horrible.

Answer (score 1):

```
    key=lambda k, v: sort_order.index(k)
```

does not work.
TypeError: () missing 1 required positional argument: v

The needed change for Python 3 would be:

```
    test_list.sort(key = lambda args : sort_order.index(args[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what changed exactly but `lambda (k, v): sort_order.index(k)` is invalid syntax in python3. You can use `lambda k, v: sort_order.index(k)` instead.